# DolphinDB syntax error: expected to close the function call sum

Tags: eval, dolphindb

Can someone help me out? I have tried the code below and it doesn’t work.

```
t=table(rand(2017.08.07..2017.08.11,20) as date,rand(`a1`a2`a3`a4,20) as ts_code,rand(10.0,20) as price)

colname="price"

eval(sql(select=sqlColAlias(<sum(colname>, `y),from=t, groupBy=sqlCol(`ts_code`)))
```

```
Syntax Error: expected to close the function call sum
```

Why it does not work?  Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I have the DolphinDB Server 1.20.9 version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sql(select=sqlColAlias(makeCall(sum,sqlCol(colname)), `y),from=t).eval()
```

Comment: There is a simpler way for this:

````sql(select=sqlColAlias(sqlCol(colname，sum), "y"), from=t).eval()````